# How to install X desktop on a custom Linux distribution without X in the official yum repo?

Tags: x11, yum, rpm

I am using a custom Linux distribution.
It is minimal.
It uses **yum** but has very small amount of packages in its official yum repo. `yum search` does not find any matching records. So far as I know, no additional repos are available.

I found RPM Find: http://www.rpm-find.net/linux/RPM/, but it seems that if I want to do it this way, I will have to download all packages according to each other's dependency list one by one. It might be okay for a small piece of software, but for X desktop, people say it could results in 100+ packages that needed to be installed. Obviously I do not want to download these packages manually.

Is there any public yum repo that I can add to yum so it can install X desktop from it, or is there a faster way to get all dependencies automatically?

Comment: Using some other repo will depend on matching glibc versions, etc.you may end up breaking things.  Do you have a compiler tool chain available?  You could get a source rpm and build it for local use...

Comment: @ivanivan Building from source does not solve dependencies.

Comment: The name of the distribution would be helpful here

Comment: The answer is probably going to end up being “use another distribution”...

Comment: try this:  ( yum groupinstall "GNOME Desktop Environment" )

Comment: @Vafa "Group does not exist." Of course. This makes no sense. If I can install them in a group, I can definitely install one of them.